# The relationship of arithmetic mean and integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The arithmetic mean of $y_i\ldots y_n$ is:
${1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i,$

If $n$ goes infinty, how to prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i={\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x) dx \over x_1-x_0},$

where $f(x)$ is a smooth function, $f(x_i)=y_i$ and $x_0<\ldots<x_i<\ldots<x_n<\ldots<x_1.$

Comment: The Trapezoidal Rule?

Comment: Hi, I may have interpreted your question incorrectly, but to find the average value (arithmetic mean) of a function over an interval it is $\frac{\int_a^b f(x)dx}{b-a}$, a derivation can be found here;http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ProofIntProp.aspx#Extras_IntPf_AvgVal

Comment: Thanks frog, good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The notation is bad because $x_1$ has two meanings (it can be confused with one of the $x_i$).

But forgetting about that, note that if you multiply both sides by $x_1-x_0$, you have the sum on the left side as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\;\Delta x$$ where $\Delta x\equiv\frac{x_1-x_0}{n}$.

Do you recognize this as part of the definition of the Riemann integral

Comment: thanks, does it mean $f(x)$ must be a smooth function?